# Gradle Sync Failed: Cause: https://downloads.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.1.2-all.zip

Tags: android, gradle, synchronization, migration

I'm at importing old project done on Eclipse.
and got updates using  Helps--> Check for Updates
then, press "Sync Project with Gradle Files" button.
so, in 2 seconds, this message appeared at Build:sync and Event log windows

Please help me with right ways of experience.

Comment: What is "this message"? Is there a full stack trace you forgot to share?

Comment: Are you certain you did an "Import" from eclipse model and not an "Open"? if you messed up your open process, just delete all the build directories, .idea and .iml files and then try again on a fresh import. Then do gradle sync

Answer (score 7):

That distribution doesn't exist (https://services.gradle.org/distributions/)

To fix it change your distributionUrl in the gradle-wrapper.properties file to a valid version. For example

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

Try going to the link and downloading the zip file.